# Unix: How to Exit Out of "/" directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am learning some elements of the Unix environment myself. I have tried to search up this question but perhaps I am not wording it correctly. It is quite possibly a very trivial question, too, but I am just not sure how to do it.

On terminal on my Mac, I know that I can do `cd /` to access my Unix directory files on terminal. However, how can I exit out of `/` and return to the previous directory I was in? I have tried `cd ..` but that does not work (why not? I don't know). I also don't want to use `cd -` because it is not necessary that my prior directory is the desired one.

Comment: The command `cd ..` go to upper directory, not previous one. And as `/` is the root you can't go in upper one.

Comment: plain `cd` should take you to your home directory (usually `/home/<username>`)

Comment: @Esther, and what if the previous directory was not user home?

Comment: Then you would use `cd -`, but OP doesn't want that for some reason. It is VERY unclear where OP actually wants to go. He wants the "previous directory", which is somehow not necessarily the "prior directory".

Comment: Sorry - it's my poor phrasing! This is what I meant: If I am in "/my_name_folder", and if I do "cd /", then "cd /etc", what I mean by previous directory is "/my_name_folder", whereas prior directory is "/". I wasn't sure to refer to "/my_name_folder" as the upper directory, since I am not knowledgeable about the sort of heirarchy here.  Would this be called the home directory? Again, sorry for the terrible wording, but that is what I meant.

Comment: Aryan, try with the commands from my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

When you are in desired directory exec

```
pushd /
```

do some operations and when you want to return exec

```
popd
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushd_and_popd

Answer (score 2):

`cd ..` takes you to the current directory's *parent*. `/` is the filesystem's root and is it's own parent.

If the "$OLDPWD" (which `cd -` uses) is not what you want, just specify where you want to go

```sh
cd /
# then
cd /some/interesting/dir
```

---

If you want some shortcuts, investigate your shell's `CDPATH` variable.

Answer (score 2):

The Unix file system is organized as a tree. The root of the tree is called `/`

[image]

In the picture above, you see a part of the tree. If you are in `/`, you can `cd` to `etc` or `usr`. In `usr`, you can `cd` to `local` or `bin`.

you can always specify the full path from root. If you are in `/etc`, you can `cd /usr/local`.

There are a number of special directories. `.` is the current directory. So, if you are in `/usr`, the following will get you to `/usr/bin`: `cd ./bin`.
`..` is the directory above. So, again from `/usr`, `cd ..` will put you in `/`. Or, if you're in `/usr/bin`, `cd ../../etc` will put you in `/etc`.